lm-sensors, CPU sensors not detected
I have a fresh install of Manjaro running on a server i have built. I have an AMD Genoa 9334 ES. On windows I can detect the correct core temperature (see attached images). On the linux OS (Ubuntu 24.04, Debian Bookworm latest + Manjaro) lm-sensors is not detecting the thermal sensors in the CPU core. The K10temp is giving the Package temperature on the motherboard sensors rather than the core. The fact this is an ES should not come into play. As it works on Windows I know its not a BIOS issue. I am running the latest kernel (6.8.8-2-MANJARO).
Linux temperatures:

Windows temperatures:

Some extra information:
(output of pwmconfig + sensors-detect CPU)
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0+git
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.
We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.
/usr/bin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
Output of sensors detect:
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0+git
# System: Supermicro Super Server [123456789]
# Board: Supermicro H13SSL-NT
# Kernel: 6.8.8-2-MANJARO x86_64
# Processor: AMD Eng Sample: 100-000000897-03 (25/17/0)
This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.
Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       NoVIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                  No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
AMD Family 19h thermal sensors...                           No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

IMPORTANT FOR ANYONE HAVING THE SAME ISSUE
Ubuntu and Debian did not have support for AMD 19h when I ran sensors-detect (unsure of the kernel I was using) but Manjaro does here. The Genoa 9334 is zen 4 which as far as im aware is
I think it should be detecting AMD Family 19h thermal sensors here.  My question is simple, how can I force it to install the module for this even though its not detecting it? I know the sensor exists and can be accessed.  Any help is appriciated but please don't tell me to run sensors-detect or that k10temp showing the packages it the best we can do because that is not the case. I am ready to cry and pull my hair out even my eyebrows.
